# How can I hide contact tabs depending on user role?

Tags: contacts, roles, contact-view

I want to give all Drupal Users with a specific role access to basic contact information from our database, but I don't want them to see things like the list of activities, groups joined, notes, cases, etc.

Is there a way to give some users the ability to view only access to a specific set of contact data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We often find that for most Drupal users who don't really 'need' access to civicrm, it is less painful for them to 'access' the data they should be able to get to via a Drupal View (which can be set with Role-based permissions). If you are not familiar with Drupal Views for Civi Contacts or CiviMemberships you may find something in our 'treasure trove' aka [Views Library](http://www.fuzion.co.nz/tags/views-library)

Answer (score 1):

In the Drupal admin bar, go to People. 
Click the Permissions tab.
From there you can give each user role access to some of civicrm but not al of it. For example, you can choose not to allow access to civicontribute, or any financial data.